# Flash plugin for Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, flash

The flash player plugin has stopped working in Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 .I cant find pepper flash for chromium either ,certain music sites require flash so are now not use-able.

Answer (score 23):

```
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

This command got flash working in Firefox for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12):

Go to Official [Adobe flash website](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), then download the  `install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz` and extract the tarball using:

```
tar -zxvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
```

You got the `libflashplayer.so`. Now copy this file to `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins` directory using:

```
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

Comment: manifest.json <- should we do anything with this file?

Comment: I have tried both Firefox ESR 52 and 60 (new, Quantum) and managed to run plugin only for specific profile at ~/.mozilla/filefox/ProfileName/plugins

Comment: I have copied`libflashplayer.so` (NPAPI) in `~/.mozilla/filefox/YourProfileName/plugins`  
Tested on 16.04 (xUbuntu) with FlashPlayer v30.  
**Note** that plugin was not loaded from `FirefoxProgramDir/plugins` as written here:  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Determining_plugin_directory_on_Linux  
 @SeekTruth, plugin works without manifest.json file.