# Audio source not appearing in pulseaudio but playing over headphone jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, external-soundcard, pavucontrol

I use a headset with internal USB sound card running on Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE 5.5 and Firefox 56.0 (64-bit). Recently playing music using the Amazon Music web player stopped working.

- Using the same setup, music from other sources, like Youtube, works without problem.
- When I start a track in the Amazon Player, it starts and the progress bar is moving. However, no music is playing over the headphones.
- When I start pavucontrol, no new entry in the playback tab is created for the audio source and there is no movement in the output devices tab.

Now for the strange part:

- When I plug my earbuds headphones into the audio jack, I hear the music Amazon is playing.
- There is still no movement in the devices tab and no entry in the playback tab.
- When I mute the internal sound card (the one that is used for the earbuds), the sound stops.

I have tried

```
alsactl restore
```

and removing the pavu config files, but both did not solve this problem. Additionally I installed virtually all pulseaudio component and added the Phonon VLC backend. I tried disabling all devices but my external sound card, but nothing worked.

Does anyone have an idea, what is going on here?

**Edit:**
On chromium, the player works and the source shows up in pavucontrol, as long as I play music from my library (i.e. tracks I 'own' as opposed to tracks I added via Prime 'for free streaming'). The other tracks start, immediately stop and skip to the next track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem with the flash player plugin being no longer supported for 16.04. Installing the chromium flash player plugin solved my problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

I found this solution in the following question which also links to additional information: [Flash plugin for Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/771988/257430)